# Will an attribute instance be created for each instance of a class in C#?

Tags: c#, attributes, instance, decorator

Will an attribute instance be created for each instance of a class in C#?

Here is what I mean. Let us suppose we have the following piece of code:

```
using System;

public class MyAttribute : Attribute
{
    public MyAttribute()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("attr got created");
    }
}

[MyAttribute()]
public class A
{
    
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        new A();
        new A();
    }
}
```

My question is: will there be created two instances of the `MyAttribute` (because there are two instances of the `A` are created) or will there be created only a single instance of the `MyAttribute` which will be shared across the `A` instances?

Also, I suspect another possible option is that no instance of the `MyAttribute` will be created, because when the above code runs nothing gets output to console.

So, it is either 0, 1 or 2 instances of the `MyAttribute` will be created and I would like to know how many exactly. And in case the answer is not 0, then why don`t I see anything in console?

Comment: They only get created once you ask it's `Type` for custom attributes: https://dotnetfiddle.net/5UjUQV

Comment: And to answer your question (which you've already answered yourself by this test). No they're not created when creating a new instance of `A`, so the answer is 0. But as shown in the fiddle above keep in mind that they can be created in other ways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Attribute instances are not created until you need them. In your sample you do not get these attributes in any way, so they are not created.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class MyAttribute : Attribute
{
    public Guid MyGuid { get; set; }

    public MyAttribute()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("attr got created");
        MyGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
    }
}

[My]
public class A
{

}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var a1 = new A();
        var a2 = new A();

        var attributes = new List<A> {a1, a2}.SelectMany(a => a.GetType().GetCustomAttributes<MyAttribute>());

        foreach (var attribute in attributes)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine($"MyAttribute has id {attribute.MyGuid}");
        }
    }
}
```

With this code you can see two different guids in console output. So answer for your question is:

New attribute instance will be created for every instance of your class but only when you need it

EDIT:
New attribute instance will be created every time you request it with GetCustomAttributes() or any similar method.

Comment: Hm. Interesting point is that `.GetCustomAttributes<MyAttribute>()` still has some info about the object on which we have called the `.GetType()`. How could it otherwise know about the attributes applied to the object. So, `.GetType()` returns a type which knows from which object it was inferred. Is it so?

Comment: Please take note that attribute is applied to the class, not its instances. We cannot get a1 from a result of a1.GetType(). In the above code instances of MyAttribute have no access to a1 nor a2.